# Display price quote per month

Tags: price, quote

Is possible to display monthly payment by product?

For example:

product 1
10$/month
For 24 months

Thanks!

Comment: To display where? As a calculated value? Could you be more precise?

Comment: Hello, like as a price, to replace it. I need to display a price but in monthly payments, for example if you buy a service for 2 years, the price is 20$ every month for 24 months.

Comment: Ok, how do you want to bill the customer at the time of placing an order? He will pay sum for 24 months for example or first rate? (sorry for "awkward" questions but this business requirements will determine eventual implementation).

Comment: In the checkout there's no payment, we will manage the order internally for every customer. The customer only see the rate of the service in the detail of order. Don't worry about the management of the order, thanks ;)

Comment: In that case i would suggest to simply add attribute on product with such a description. It is most straightforward and simple solution.  Unless it should be somehow calculated eg, current product price * months where months will be a hidden attribute, then it will require some customizations.

Comment: Hey! You're right! It sounds a cool solution, thanks Bartosz Herba! I will try it. Regards.